# Throwing fake errors will stop the script?

Tags: javascript

I didn't use `throw new ReferenceError` much before, and when I am using, I found out it will stop the script:

```
alert("a");  //Yes
throw new ReferenceError("Error.");  //Yes
alert("b");  //Nope
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uKEZ4/

I just want to throw an error in the console without stopping the whole script. I tried to do this:

```
alert("a");  //Yes
try{
    throw new ReferenceError("Error.");  //Yes
}catch(e){}
alert("b");  //Yes
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uKEZ4/1/

This will work, but I don't think this is the best approach. What is the best way to display an error message without stopping the script?

PS:

```
console.warn("Error");
```

won't work on IE.
​

Comment: You have only explained what you do, but you forgot to mention **why** you need this to do

Comment: I am using it in kind of like setting page, and it will store data depending on the checkboxes. But the checkboxes won't always be there, so I want to display an error message, but the script will continue to run. Anyway I just want to know is that the best way to do it.

Comment: so how `console.warn` can be useful for general user?

Comment: Exceptions were designed to interrupt current function run and go up the stack for the next `catch`. If you don't want the script to be interrupted - don't use exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is by design. Exception handling in JavaScript works just like it does in many other languages: C#, Java, Ruby, etc.

When an exception is thrown it *will* unwind the stack and it *will* skip execution of code until it is caught with a `catch` (where it will "resume" execution). If there is no `catch`, then it just skips off the end of the code entirely (script element, source file, REPL, etc). `finally` is also an option in cases (to "resume" execution), but there is nothing like `On Error Resume Next`; that's just not JavaScript.

There is nothing to change this behavior.
(I recommend just [shimming IE](https://github.com/kayahr/console-shim) to support `console`.)

Comment: Looks like I will just forget about IE. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Error` just a simply `Object`.whataever you `throw`, they always break the exec flow.